# Find the value of two constants in a probability density function

Tags: probability, functions

I have this exercise:

The continuous random variable X has p.d.f. f(x) where:

$f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{x}{3} - \frac{2}{3}, & \mbox{if } 2 \le x \le 3 \\ \alpha, & \mbox{if }3 \le x \le 5 \\ 2-\beta x & \mbox{if } 5 \le x \le 6 \\ 0 & \mbox{otherwise} \end{cases}$

find $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

How can I find $\alpha$ and $\beta$ ?
I tried to do that with the following equation:

$\int_2^3(\frac{x}{3}- \frac{2}{3})dx + \int_3^5 \alpha \, dx + \int_5^6 (2-\beta x)dx = 1 \\ \frac{1}{3} \int_2^3x \, dx - \frac{2}{3} \int_2^3 dx + \alpha \int_3^5 dx + 2\int_5^6 dx - \beta \int_5^6 x \, dx = 1 \\ \frac{1}{3}[\frac{x^2}{2}]_2^3 - \frac{2}{3}[x]_2^3 + \alpha[x]_3^5 + 2[x]_5^6- \beta[\frac{x^2}{2}]_5^6 = 1 \\ \frac{5}{6} - \frac{2}{3} + 2\alpha + 2 - \frac{11}{2} \beta = 1$

arrived here I have tried also to maintain $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to the left side and trying to do something in addition, and I have multiplied by 6 both sides to obtain a integer number:

$2\alpha - \frac{11}{2} \beta = -\frac{7}{6} \\ 12 \alpha - \frac{11}{2} \cdot 6 \beta = -7 \\ 12 \alpha - 33 \beta = -7$

arrived here I really don't know how to continue.
Please, can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe, the continuity of the function gives another equation

Comment: That the random variable is continuous does not imply the density function $f(x)$ is continuous.  You do know that $f(x)\ge0$ for all $x$, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the hint of [Med](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/261160/med) you get two equations. The argument is that  you have $\texttt{overlapping intervals}$. And the value of the function must be equal for equal $x$ values.

**1.** The value of the function must be equal for the upper limit of the first interval and the lower limit of the second interval (common point):

$$\frac33-\frac23=\alpha$$

**2.** The value of the function must be equal for the upper limit of the second interval and the lower limit of the third interval (common point):

$$\alpha=2-5\beta$$

With these two equations you can evaluate the values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Finally you can check if these values satisfy your equation $12 \alpha - 33 \beta = -7$

Comment: Unfortunately, the hint provided by Med is not correct.

Comment: @DilipSarwate You mean that it contradicts the comment of kimchi lover or what is your argument ?

Comment: As kimchi points out quite correctly, a continuous random variable does not necessarily have a continuous pdf. So, using continuity of the pdf at $x=3$ and at $x=6$ gives you _a_ possible solution for $\alpha$ and $\beta$; possible because it might be that the parameters are such that the pdf turns out to be negative for some values of $x$. Also, why not insist that the pdf have value $0$ at $x=6$ which forces continuity at $x=6$ instead of at $x=5$?

Comment: I still don´t understand, especially why you use $x=6$. My argument is that the intervals have common points, which should results in equal values for $f(x)$.

Comment: You are reading far too much into the $\leq$ signs used by the OP; they could well be sheer carelessness on the OP's part in transcribing the actual problem posed.

Comment: Maybe or maybe not. But it is a valid function and I firstly have to assume that the posting is right, if there are no obvious errors/contradictions. And additionally the results are matching.